# Multiplication of long type by double type during update query (HQL)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, grails-orm

I have next entity

```groovy
class DomTestEntity {

    Long completeValue
    Long rawValue

}
```

I want to update completeValue using rawValue multiplied by double number(rate). Wrote simple method to do that:

```groovy
def testHql(){
    Double rate = 0.7
    DomTestEntity.executeUpdate("update DomTestEntity item set item.completeValue = item.rawValue * :rate", [rate: rate])

    render view: "index", model: [message: "Test complete"]
}
```

but it throw an error:

```
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long. Stacktrace follows: - [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at companyname.TestController$$EOQBEOjI.testHql(TestController.groovy:122)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

At the same time sql query works fine:

```groovy
def testHql(){
    Double rate = 0.7
    sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery("update dom_test_entity e set e.complete_value = e.raw_value * ${rate}").executeUpdate()

    render view: "index", model: [message: "Test complete"]
}
```

**How to avoid casting double value to long in Hql? or How to write correct hql query that works as sql query?**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save a double value into a Long column. Which is not allowed. Either you have to change the type of 'completeValue' to Double (meaning changing the underlying DB column type appropriately) or store the nearest long value as the result.

Comment: Yes, I know that column has Long type and value is double, but when I use sql query it automatically cast or round calculated value to long, that is what I want from hql query. As for type I need to store completeValue as Long not Double. How can I store the nearest long value as the result?